# SoundPool not play a mp3?

Tags: android, soundpool

I'm trying execute a mp3 file with SoundPool. I loaded the mp3 with SoundPool.load but when I try SoundPool.play doesn't work and not throws any exception. I'm using API21.

How can I solve it ?

I'm trying this.

```
public class CustomSoundPool {

    //SDK Version
    public SoundPool getSoundPool(){
        SoundPool sounds = null;

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
            .build();

            sounds = new SoundPool.Builder()
            .setAudioAttributes(attributes)
            .build();
        }else{
            sounds = new SoundPool(5,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
        }
        return sounds;
    }

}




 /** play sound with error or success */
        private void playSound(){
            SoundPool sound = new CustomSoundPool().getSoundPool();
            if(resposta.getValor() == 1){
                int soundId = sound.load(getView().getContext(), R.raw.sucesso, 1);
                sound.play(soundId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
            }else{
                int soundId = sound.load(getView().getContext(), R.raw.erro, 1);
                sound.play(soundId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
            }
            sound.release();            
        }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're releasing `SoundPool` too early. Do a release later i.e. in `onDestroy` method of `Activity`. Now the sound will not have enough time to be played before all memory and native resources used by the `SoundPool` object will be released. Also, you're trying to play sound to quickly before it'll actually manage to load. You can't use `play` before your sound is loaded. Use `SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener#onLoadComplete` to wait until sound is loaded and inside listener play your sound.

```
SoundPool soundPool;
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
     AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
          .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
          .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
          .build();

          soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
                        .setAudioAttributes(attributes)
                        .build();       
}
else {
    soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
}
soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
        soundPool.play(sampleId, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f);
    }
});
soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sucesso, 1);
```

Comment: even I doing your suggestion doesn't work. Play not execute the sound